# Is there a OpenID provider in Europe?

Tags: openid

Does anybody know a Europe-based provider for OpenID?
I am not using one of the well-known bigger services (Yahoo,..).

Answer (score 4):

I have developed one myself, [LoginBuzz](http://www.loginbuzz.com/en). It is primarily Danish and I have first translated many parts of it the last week, but it should be fully functional.

It supports simple registration, attribute exchange and PAPE. I have also implemented CardSpace support and text messaging (only available in Denmark at the moment) for a more secure authentication process. In a near future it should get support for client certificates as well.

My main goal is keeping it simple and fast. What you really want is to go back to the site that requested the authentication, not to spend time on the provider´s site.

I am very interested in feedback for making it a better service.

Comment: Has that provider moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

And of course, there is the [Clavid](http://www.clavid.ch/) OpenID provider supporting many secure authentication mechanisms.